# DSNless connection to Oracle database using DAO Database object in VBA

Tags: vba, oracle, odbc, database-connection

it's possible to use DSNless connection with wiht an object created from DAO Database class in VBA.

The connection to database using ODBC connection works as expected, however if you use other connection string types as mentioned www.connectionstrings.com the connection is not established.

```
public Sub dbConnectTest()

Dim myDB As DAO.Database
Dim conn As String
Dim tns As String
Dim odbcString as String

odbcString = "ODBC;DSN=Location Name;UID=ANUSER;PWD=apassword;DBQ=A_TNS_NAME"

' this part works
   Set myWorkspace = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("APPNAME", "admin", "")
   Set myDB = myWorkspace.OpenDatabase(Name:="", Options:=dbDriverNoPrompt, ReadOnly:=True, _
                                                        Connect:=odbcString)
 ' same here                                                        
    Set myDB = OpenDatabase("", False, False, "ODBC")                                                       
' any of below part don't work

 odbcString = "Driver=(Oracle in XEClient);dbq=server:1980/SID;UID=ANUSER;PWD=apassword;"
 odbcString = "Driver={Oracle in OraHome92};Dbq=A_TNS_NAME;UID=ANUSER;PWD=apassword;"
 odbcString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=1980)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SID)));Uid=ANUSER;Pwd=apassword;"
     Set myDB = OpenDatabase("", False, False, odbcString)                                                      



end sub
```

I want to change the connection string due to the fact that even if myDB object is set to nothing after a user logout, when a new login is requested with a new password the old connection string is somehow preserved and instead of a connection error a successfully connection object is retrieved.

Comment: Please show us your connection string. You may use the OLE DB driver rather than ODBC

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to an Oracle 11g instance using the following connection string and call to OpenDatabase.  I'm using the version of DAO available through the reference "Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object":

```
' Construct connection string
oracxnstr = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=fake.url.com)(PORT=fakePortNo))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=fakeSID)));Uid=fakeUid;Pwd=fakePw;"
```

I've obviously used fake parameters in this string so I'm not exposing my database.

```
' attempt to connect to oracle
Set oradb = dbws.OpenDatabase("", 1, True, oracxnstr)
```

The Microsoft DAO documentation is woefully inadequate, so I'm pointing out the differences between my code and yours that might be relevant:

- I'm using the connection string parameter "Server" instead of "CONNECTSTRING."  However, either one works in my system.
- I'm using the connection string parameter "SID" instead of "SERVICE_NAME."  This also did not make a difference... this time. But for reasons I don't understand, I know that it has made a difference in the past.  I don't understand why it does sometimes make a difference.  (I'm an Oracle novice but I think the Oracle configuration has something to do with it.)
- For the 2nd parameter to the OpenDatabase method, I'm using 1 instead of true.  This is the dbDriverNotPrompt enumerated constant. If I change to true, this also doesn't make a difference.
- If I use DAO 3.6 I **do** get a run-time error 3151 "ODBC connection failed."  I'm wondering if the older version isn't able to handle DSN-less or TNS-less connection strings to Oracle?

The only other difference I can think of is that maybe your Oracle username/password account has Read Only permissions, while the 3rd parameter to the OpenDatabase method is set to false?